# getting element from td (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript

How can i get the href from such a table?

```
<table class="file_slot" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=3>
<tr>*****************</tr>
<tr>
        <td><b>Size:</b></td>
        <td>452<small><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></small></td>
     </tr>
```

I tried using getElementsByClassName but i don't get to the `<a>` tag.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your quick answers. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
var href =  document.querySelector('.file_slot a').href;
```

Comment: Should be noted that, depending on what results are required, this could be slower than getElementsByTagName: http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname

Comment: @Blade0rz Obviously OP doesn't want all a elements but the one of his table. And this would still appear instantaneous for all practical purposes.

Comment: Indeed, but for the wider audience or the two people who upvoted the question, it may be applicable.

Answer (score 3):

You want [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName) instead:

`var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var file=  document.querySelector('.file_slot a');
file.href="http://www.google.com";
```